# Thinstation Citrix ICA PNAgent Configuration Help

Tags: linux, ssl, citrix, thin-client

I have an old Thinstation build that connects directly to a Citrix server via ICA.  I have a new Citrix farm that has an SSL relay out front, and I can't seem to figure out how I connect to this new farm using the PNAgent module.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research it doesn't appear that this is possible with Thinstation.  I have, instead, built a custom SLAX distro which works via cd boot and starts the ica client.